# Swift 3 and EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler throwing exception

Tags: swift, swift3, eventkit

I tried to request access to the calendar using following code:

```
EKEventStore().requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event, completion: {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError!) in

    print("Got permission = \(success); error = \(error)")
 })
```

Xcode wants to add `as! EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler`
because it says

> Cannot convet value of type (Bool, NSError!) ...".

But when I add this the app crashes with **EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION** and no further explanation. Any ideas whats wrong here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I downvote you and I explain why: it is sufficient read the entire compiler error to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 3 you need to use `Error` instead of `NSError` check [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekeventstorerequestaccesscompletionhandler) for more detail.

```
EKEventStore().requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event, completion: {
    (success: Bool, error: Error?) in  

    print("Got permission = \(success); error = \(error)")

})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it!